# Where do electrons get the energy to remain in orbit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, atoms, atomic-physics

As we know electrons continuously revolve around the nuclus without falling in it at a high velocity beating it's force of attraction. My question is where do electrons get energy to revolve around the nucleus and withstand its force of attraction.

Comment: I wonder where the Earth gets its energy to withstand the attraction of the Sun... ;)

Comment: Electrons don't revolve around the nucleus... that's still a classical (at best semi-classical) picture. The electrons are described by their quantum mechanical orbitals around an atom. I haven't explained anything, but now you have some more words to google. :)